# Foreground service has been killed automatically when MobileAds initializes

Tags: android, admob, foreground-service, google-mobile-ads

In my main class in

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
{ 
 ..some code

 //first start foreground service 
 Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(this, ForegroundService.class);
 ContextCompat.startForegroundService(this, serviceIntent);
 //then i'm starting admob
 MobileAds.initialize(this,"ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111");
 mAddView = findViewById(R.id.adView);
 AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
 mAddView.loadAd(adRequest);

..some code
}
```

Without MobileAds.initialize() my foreground service is not being killed when i'm closing application.
With MobileAds.initialize() my foreground service is being killed.

Does any one know why? How to solve that?

Answer (score 0):

You must clear this line

```
MobileAds.initialize(this,"ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111");
```

And add the following line to the manifest instead

```
<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
        android:value="ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx~yyyyyyyyyy"/>
```